# get-aduser returns unwanted fields

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script to output names for a report so I'm trying to use

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase  "OU=Staff,DC=solutions,DC=local" 
           -Properties GivenName, Surname | Export-Csv -NoType $filepath;
```

It works fine but it returns a csv file with extra unwanted fields

It should only return `GivenName` and `Surname`, however it returns:

```
DistinguishedName
Enabled
GivenName
Name
ObjectClass
ObjectGUID
SamAccountName
SID
Surname
UserPrincipalName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a pattern like this:

```
$Props = @(
'GivenName',
'SurName'
)

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase  "OU=Staff,DC=solutions,DC=local" -Properties $Props |
Select $Props |  Export-Csv -NoType $filepath
```

Then just change/rearrange the properties to select and the order to output them in the $Props array.

Answer (score 3):

Some properties are returned by defualt. `-Properties` is used to specify the properties you need to make sure that they are included if they're not part of the default properties.

To only export the properties you need, run your data through `Select-Object` before exporting, like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase  "OU=Staff,DC=solutions,DC=local" -Properties GivenName, Surname |
Select-Object GivenName, Surname |
Export-Csv -NoType $filepath
```

Comment: I like this one too, Same idea without the variable But I think the other answer is more resuable for other projects

Comment: Nwm ;-) I only provide answers to the problems being asked. Tweaking it to ex. use a variable was not part of the question and is something I expect others to be able to solve on their own or ask in a separate question. SO questions and answer are supposed to be short and precise.

Comment: +1 for answering the question as asked.  I threw in the pattern because it's not always intuitive that it works that way, and didn't really expect it to get marked as the answer.